# C# Socket Programming, How can you choose which client to connect to from the server client?

Tags: c#, client

Im making a program in c#, the server side program listens to a port and the client connect to the server. But I want to pick which client to connect to when all the clients are trying to connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each connection that's made to your server gives you a reference to a `Socket` object that you can use for sending data back or *serving* your clients, e.g.:

```
Socket handler = listener.Accept()
// ...
// do your processing
// ...
byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Sending response to client");
handler.Send(msg);
```

Don't lose the reference to that Socket object.